# Ionic hybrid app: Select multiple not working on some devices

Tags: html, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a selectbox where you can select multiple failure types:

`<select name="failureType" ng-model="model.failureType" required ng-options="item.name for item in data.failureType" form="regFailForm" label='{{"FAILURETYPE" | translate}}'
        multiple>
    <option value=""></option>
</select>`

This "works on our machines" but on some devices of the client they can't select multiple items. Like for example the LG G2 (LG-D802) with Android 4.4.2.

Is there  a fix for this?

[image: Moto G]
[image: LG G2]

Comment: Correct `<select name="failureType" ng-model="model.failureType" required ng-options="item.name for item in data.failureType" form="regFailForm" label='{{"FAILURETYPE" | translate}}'
        multiple="true">` reference http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/select/Select/

Comment: The html standard correct version would be `multiple="multiple"`
I changed it to this but the problem is that I don't have a G2 to test it. So I hope somebody has the proof that this works...

Answer (score 0):

i got an issue similar to this , i fixed it with cross walk project it makes all version of android behave the same but it added extra size to your apk

Check [Here](http://blog.ionic.io/crosswalk-comes-to-ionic/)

OR Check from docs  [ON](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/browsers.html)

Comment: you can still edit the content of this answer. Bring the relevant part of the code, excerpt from the page here, so that even if the link is dead down the line the gist of the content is available

Answer (score 0):

correct code:

```
<select  name="failureType" ng-model="model.failureType" required 
  ng-options="item.name for item in data.failureType" 
  form="regFailForm"     label='{{"FAILURETYPE" | translate}}' 
  ng-multiple="true" multiple>
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

Comment: I don't think ng-multiple will does anything other than making multiple dynamically changeable. And it is removed from angular: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2113